# dynamic_reconfigure: cfg file generation not producing __init__.py file correctly

Tags: python, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've encountered an issue with dynamic_reconfigure (working with python) not producing an `__init__.py` in the configuration module directory:

As expected, the generator produces a new directory `my_module` (with a `cfg` directory within) in my `src` directory. It *does* create an `__init__.py` file within the `cfg` directory but *not* within `my_module` itself. Python doesn't recognize this as a module and I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named my_module.cfg

Manually creating an `__init__.py` file within the `my_module` directory solves this problem. Is anyone else encountering this issue? Is it a bug or do I have a setting wrong somewhere? Thanks in advance!

System: Ubuntu 10.10, Python Version: 2.7.1, ROS Electric and Diamondback

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11772/dynamic_reconfigure:-cfg-file-generation-not-producing-__init__.py-file-correctly/) by [haroldsoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1305/haroldsoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on 2011-11-22**:
We have the same issue here. It seems the cause is  `rosed dynamic_reconfigure parameter_generator.py` fail to generate the necessary **init**.py. Ticket submitted  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5259

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-11-03**:
I have the same issue here (Ubuntu 11.04; Python 2.7.1; ROS electric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you suffer from this in, e.g., mypackage, go to mypackage/src/mypackage, and touch **init**.py

For example:

```
rosmake mypackage
roscd mypackage/src/mypackage 
touch __init__.py
```

Then it should run.

Steve.

---

Originally posted by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) with karma: 306 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
This is a useful temporary workaround, but not a fix for the problem, which will recur when someone else checks out `mypackage`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a bug. Please open a ticket.

I have not seen it, perhaps because I already had a `src/my_package/__init__.py` for other reasons.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1